# Interacting SQL Server database via SMS in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, sms-gateway, bulksms

I am working on an B2B ASP.Net app, where I am targeting people having mobile phone. I want to know if i can use my sms gateway two way , for both sending and receiving msgs. I havent used sms gateway earlier. 
I want such a gateway that i can send and process messages automatically via my app.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: this article might help you
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMS_message_from_SQL.aspx?q=asp.net+sms+application and see below links http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=asp.net+sms+sample+code&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=21353ad3a380c9b7&biw=1435&bih=710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/)

It's a great service that allows you to send/receive SMS via it's API ... see [here](http://www.twilio.com/api/sms)